# How do I fix a Floating Point Calculation issue?

Tags: python, if-statement, math, floating-point, integer

So, last week, I got some work sent to me for Python 3, and one of the questions goes as follows: "Write (a) program which inputs the year. Your program should output whether it is a leap year or not. To work out if it is a leap year, test whether it is exactly divisible by 4."

This is what I've got so far:

```
yearStr = input("Please input a year: ")
year = float(yearStr)

calculation = year / 4

print(calculation)

if calculation == .0:
    print("This is a leap year.")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year.")
```

When I run the program, the IF statement doesn't work as intended. Could you help me, please?

Comment: There are a lot of problems with floating point numbers in binary notation. You can use `//` to round the number to int.

Comment: Why whould you _ever_ convert a year to a float when needing to test for leap-year? Use an int().  Also you need the modulo operator to check if something divides without remainder - not a normal division. This reeks of homework. The only way year/4 would ever be 0 is if year was 0 to begin with

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Well, the question all but *says* it's homework. Nothing wrong with that. It's a valid question, not a lazy homework dump.

Answer (score 1):

Division does not yield zero if the number is evenly divisible, so this method cannot work.

Rather, use the [modulo (`%`) operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) to get the remainder of the division:

```
year = int(yearStr)
calculation = year % 4
if calculation == 0: # leap year
    ...
```

And note that strictly speaking, leap year determination is a bit more complex than just being divisible by four. But it'll do for the next 79 years.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the performance of the code. To check if the year is leap, you have to put different conditions. You can now use this code:

```py
year = int(input("Please input a year: "))

if ((year%400 == 0) or ((year%4 == 0) and (year%100 != 0))):
    print("This is a leap year.")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year.")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing calculation with 0, which is true only if the year was 0. You can check if integer value is equal to number itself.

```
calculation = year / 4

print(calculation)

if int(calculation) == calculation:
    print("This is a leap year.")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year.")
```

Still, this is not a good way to solve this problem, there is a remainder operation - %. For example `5 % 2 = 1`. You can use it this way:

```
yearStr = input("Please input a year: ")
year = float(yearStr)

print(calculation)

if calculation % 4 == 0:
    print("This is a leap year.")
else:
    print("This is not a leap year.")
```